# How can I sculpt a small/fine line?

Tags: sculpting

In sculpt mode, using the draw tool, I can only seem to make indents in my object if the change is massive (i.e. taking a massive chunk out of it), if i set the brush settings to have a smaller radius or a stronger strength, barely any change is made.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snake hook brush with dynotopo enabled.

The snake hook brush is designed to pull geometry into thin strands depending on brush size. Dynotopo is recommended because as you pull vertices out, it loses more and more detail until the tip of the line has only 1 or 2 vertices. Dynotopo will automatically create new geometry do you don't need to worry about that.